# laptop sees two connections when HD TV is plugged, but no image

Tags: 12.04, kernel, hdmi, xrandr, dvi

With Apple Macbook Air 1,1 (Early 2008) and Ubuntu 12.04 with kernel Linux 3.2.0-68-generic-pae, when I connect it to an HD TV via the micro-DVI to DVI (Apple adapter) --> DVI to HDMI (I tried two different cables) I get the TV recognized in System Settings -> Displays, but the TV only gets a completely *black screen* signal (i.e. it gets a signal, because if I unplug the cable or disable the TV screen in Ubuntu the TV then says 'no signal', but this signal is just black screen).

Note that the DVI adapter works well with other DVI screens in Linux, while the above HDMI setup works well in Windows, so it must be a Linux-related problem.

The TV is Philips 32pfl4007m/08 but in system settings -> displays it gets named philips consumer electronics 58''

The problem should be that the graphics chipset is reporting a single device being connected to both HDMI and TV1, as one can check in the output from xrandr (with cable plugged in):

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1280x800+0+12 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 286mm x 179mm
   1280x800       61.2*+
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1280mm x 720mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     24.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1360x768       59.8  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   640x480        60.0  
TV1 unknown connection (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   848x480        59.9 +
   640x480        59.9 +
   1024x768       59.9  
   800x600        59.9
```

The command `lsmod | grep i915` gives

```
i915                  428317  4 
drm_kms_helper         45466  1 i915
drm                   197641  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13199  1 i915
video                  19115  1 i915
```

With lspci I get

```
Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller
```

also

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device 00a2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5110 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: intelfb, i915

00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device 00a2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at 90100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

and `sudo lshw -C display` gives

```
  *-display:0             
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:42 memory:90000000-900fffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:5110(size=8)
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:90100000-901fffff
```

and `randr --prop` gives

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 286mm x 179mm
    EDID:
        00ffffffffffff000610739c01010101
        10110103801d12780a90b59958528e26
        1e505400000001010101010101010101
        010101010101521c00a0502017303020
        36001eb3100000180000000100061020
        00000000000000000a20000000fe0042
        313333455730332056300a20000000fe
        00436f6c6f72204c43440a20202000d4
    BACKLIGHT: 3906 (0x00000f42)    range:  (0,24385)
    Backlight: 3906 (0x00000f42)    range:  (0,24385)
    scaling mode:   Full aspect
        supported: None         Full         Center       Full aspect 
   1280x800       61.2*+
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1280mm x 720mm
    EDID:
        00ffffffffffff00410c000001010101
        03140103808048780ae692a3544a9926
        0f4a4c2108008bc08180a94001010101
        010101010101023a801871382d40582c
        450000d05200001e023a80d072382d40
        102c458000d05200001e000000fc0050
        68696c697073204654560a20000000fd
        00303e0f4611000a20202020202001c9
        020331f152101f202221051404131203
        1102160715060126091f071507508301
        00006a030c003000382d802e2ee30503
        01011d803e73382d407e2c458000d052
        00001e011d80d0721c1620102c258000
        d05200009e011d00bc52d01e20b82855
        4000d05200001e011d8018711c162058
        2c250000d05200009e00000000000002
    Broadcast RGB:  Full
        supported: Full         Limited 16:2
    audio:  auto
        supported: off          auto         on          
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     24.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1360x768       59.8  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   640x480        60.0  
TV1 unknown connection (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    bottom margin: 37 (0x00000025)  range:  (0,100)
    right margin: 46 (0x0000002e)   range:  (0,100)
    top margin: 36 (0x00000024) range:  (0,100)
    left margin: 54 (0x00000036)    range:  (0,100)
    mode:   NTSC-M
        supported: NTSC-M       NTSC-443     NTSC-J       PAL-M       
                   PAL-N        PAL          480p@59.94Hz 480p@60Hz   
                   576p         720p@60Hz    720p@59.94Hz 720p@50Hz   
                   1080i@50Hz   1080i@60Hz   1080i@59.94H
   848x480        59.9 +
   640x480        59.9 +
   1024x768       59.9  
   800x600        59.9
```